# mysql dump using php Codeigniter , server issue with godaddy

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using php to get backup of mysql database.
On localhost it's working fine and the command is run as following:

```
$cmd = 'D:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqldump --user=' .$db['username'].' --password=  '. $db['password'] .'     --host='.$db['host'].'  '.$db['database'].' > '.FCPATH.$filename;
system($cmd,$return);
```

This works perfect when at localhost, but I want to this at godaddy hosting, so I don't know how to find the mysqldump path or how to store the .sql file.

at local my app directory is this
http://localhost/backup_app/
and folder i am using to store is 
http://localhost/backup_app/DB_Backup but actual path that i given to store .sql file is using FCPATH
i.e `D:\xampp\htdocs\backup_app` and I don't know how to generate this path on godaddy.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You tagged to question with codeigniter. Once I done this. I am sharing the code with you, lets hope it will work for your version of CI.

In version 2.x, CI dbforge class not supporting to `mysqli` driver, so I set the driver to `mysql`.

```
$db['group_one']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
```

Define the path in constants to store the file.

```
define('ADMIN_DOCS_PATH','adminDocs/');
```

The code to take backup and store the file on disk.

```
public function getDatabaseBackup()
{
    $this->db = $this->load->database('group_one', TRUE);
    $this->load->dbutil();
    $doc_name = 'DatabaseBackup'.date('YmdHis').'.sql.zip';
    $prefs = array(
            'tables'      => array(),           // Array of tables to backup.
            'ignore'      => array(),           // List of tables to omit from the backup
            'format'      => 'zip',             // gzip, zip, txt
            'filename'    => $doc_name,         // File name - NEEDED ONLY WITH ZIP FILES
            'add_drop'    => TRUE,              // Whether to add DROP TABLE statements to backup file
            'add_insert'  => TRUE,              // Whether to add INSERT data to backup file
            'newline'     => "\n"               // Newline character used in backup file
          );
    $backup =& $this->dbutil->backup($prefs);
    $this->load->helper('file');
    write_file('./'.ADMIN_DOCS_PATH.$doc_name, $backup);
}
```

Try this, also confirm your CI version and its support to `dbforge` class to download the database dump.

Comment: thankyou its working but i dont want to use it.. i want to use mysqldump command like in mine


mine script works perfect only issues with godaddy